# Changing date format from database on view file

Tags: php, laravel

My app users can select a date from a form and submit to my database. I want to show the date on their profile page.

To show the date I use the following, which works fine. However, it displays YY,MM,DD and I want 'd M, Y.

`{{$group->group_date}}`

So, I updating the code to `{{$group->group_date->format('d M, Y')}}` but that throws up an error `Call to a member function format() on string`

Comment: i tried your code and it is working. Can you show the code where you get that `$group` variable

Comment: You want to see the GroupController.php? There's quite a bit of code on their but I could add it to my original post maybe?

Comment: Thanks @JG Escarilla I missed those, am reading the now.

Comment: The solution was partially found in the duplicate link you offered. The answer was to not add anything to my Model, and simply use this code in the blade file```{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($group->group_date)->format('Y-m-d') }}```

Comment: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($group->group_date)->formatLocalized('%d %b %Y') }}

Answer (score 0):

the date returned from database is treated as a string. you can't format it. you have to cast it as a date in your model.

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['group_date'];
}
```

Now you can format it as you wish.

```
{{$group->group_date->format('d M, Y')}}
```

Comment: Adding that in my model gives me a new error ```syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)```